# Optimizing over Unitary matrices

Tags: optimization, logarithms, inner-products, unitary-matrices

Let's say I have a matrix,

$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
I need to find a unitary matrix that takes each of the columns from this matrix, transforms it and creates a new matrix $M'$:

$$
v_1 = U \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, v_2 = U \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}, 
M' = \begin{bmatrix}v_1 \;\;\; v_2\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then, I am calculating a function involving the maximum inner product between the vectors of $M$ and vectors of $M'$. Like so:

$$
\text{max overlap} = \underset{u \in M, v \in M'}{max} -\log \langle u | v \rangle^2,
$$

i.e. which pair of vectors from $M$ and $M'$ gives back the maximum overlap, then take the log squared.

I am wondering, is there a way to formulate it as an optimization problem? How do I find the optimal $U$ that maximizes this overlap? TIA.

Comment: Does it have a maximum? Take $U\to0$.

Comment: Is it like if U is almost 0 matrix? Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Yes. If the vectors $v$ are small or perpendicular to $u$, then their log is large negative.